# Container task settings for azure batch task Using CLI

Tags: azure, docker-container, azure-cli, azure-batch

I am trying a task in azure batch, I want to add Container settings for the batch task using CLI.

I don't see any information on how to add the container settings using CLI. can anyone help me?

Comment: What do you mean the Container setting? For what purpose?

Comment: I want to run docker tasks using CLI but I think its not possible to run container tasks.I have seen only SDK support like .net, java , python, nodeJS

Comment: Why not, you can use the custom image that installed Azure CLI to create the Batch node. Then you can run CLI task in it. Also with Docker.

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently available as a command line parameter to the CLI.  Full functionality is possible by specifying the Task-Add REST API JSON to the --json-file parameter(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/batchservice/task/add).

Comment: Thank you for responding. My goal was to create a release pipeline in azure devops and write a CLI script to submit jobs to azure batch

Comment: Hmm, in that case Ragu's comment above would likely work best. Otherwise you would likely need a script to write the json file which is less than ideal for your use case.